# Unable to build Flutter project after upgrade SDK to 3.10.1

Tags: flutter, debugging, build

I'm getting the following error when running debug mode after upgrading Flutter to the latest 3.10.1.

```
    file_version_info.dart:16:17: Error: Field 'wCodePage' cannot be nullable or have type 'Null', it must be `int`, `double`, `Pointer`, or a subtype of `Struct` or `Union`.
      external int? wCodePage;
                    ^
    Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1201
```

I have tried to clean the build and upgrade packages but nothing helps. It works when I down grade SDK back to 3.7.2. Appreciate any helps.

Comment: Try saving anything precious out of your android folder, then deleting the folder entirely, then "flutter create ." to regenerate it, and move precious things back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my issue. I was using a package named `new_version` which uses depreciated package `package_info_plus_windows`. Everything worked after I removed the trouble package.  I think that this is an issue with Flutter with so many third-party packages that they may cause incompatibility issues as Flutter version advances.

Comment: How did you pinpoint the package?

Answer (score 0):

I found my issue. I was using a package named new_version which uses depreciated package package_info_plus_windows. Everything worked after I removed the trouble package. I think that this is an issue with Flutter with so many third-party packages that they may cause incompatibility issues as Flutter version advances.